# How to check for NOT this number in SoapUI Assertion

Tags: regex, soapui, assertions

I am writing some Soap UI tests and am trying to figure out if there is a way with regular expressions to check for a string that does not contain a specific number.  In this one case I want to make sure that when I get a response that my recordCount field DOES NOT contain 0.  I thought this might be easier but while I can see a way to check for a set of numbers the regular expression for not this doesn't seem to work.  Probably only detects characters and not numbers.

My XML contains this:

```
<recordCount>0</recordCount>
```

What I want is something like

`recordCount>[^0]`

so I can make sure recordCount shows up in the response, but also check that at least the first number it finds is not a 0.  Is there any way to do this?

**Edit:**  Using SiKing's answer I just used the NotContains to look for recordCount>0 ; this covers the couple of cases where I don't look for specific data only how many records are returned and in those cases it just needs to be more than 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it have to be regular expression?

You can use either of the following XPath assertions, for all of which the expected result is `false`:

```
//*:recordCount = 0
exists(//*:recordCount[text()='0'])
```

Comment: I'm more used to Regular Expressions, didn't think you could do this in Soap UI but I'm still getting used to it.  I will try this, thanks!

Comment: :) "I suppose it is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail." --Maslow

Answer (score 3):

Using regular expressions you could do something like that:

```
(?s).*<recordCount>[^0]</recordCount>(?s).*
```

When using regular expressions in an assertion in SoapUI, you have to take whitespace and line breaks into account. In the example code `(?s).*` works as a wildcard that includes all whitespace and line breaks.