# Conditional Regex in SoapUI assertions

Tags: regex, soap, soapui

I've faced a problem: I would like to use conditional regex in assertion to check if my ws replies alright. I ask for list of Football Matches that had from 5 to 10 goals, so I send something like that in my request:

```
<goalsFrom>5</goalsFrom>
<goalsTo>10</goalsTo>
```

And now I would like to check if my webservice works okay. So first of all, I need to check if there were any matches fulfilling the condition (because I might get numberOfMatches=0 which doesn't mean it works wrong). And IF YES, I'd like to check if in response there are values like that:

```
<goals>6</goals> or <goals>10</goals>
```

but no:

```
<goals>4</goals> or <goals>11</goals>
```

Is there any way to do that? Couldn't figure it out browsing their forums.

Comment: So are you using `<goals>` or `<goalsFrom>` and `<goalsTo>`?

Comment: <goals> is used in response. <goalsFrom> and <goalsTo> in request. But does it matter?

Comment: How about: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25432549/3124333 ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex for validation:

`<goals>([5-9]|10)<\/goals>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vH8mZ2/1)

Comment: This doesn't work in SoapUI. I don't understand it's regex support. +First of all I need to check if I got <numberOfMatches> greater than 0. So I need a condition check.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish that using [Script Assertion in SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/validating-messages/using-script-assertions.html), which allows you to write assertion scripts in Groovy or JavaScript.